# Consulta entre multiplos inserts

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho uma api que está a cada segundo (variando o tempo conforme a resposta do webservice) enviando dados para serem inseridos no nodejs(v12.11.0) de diversas unidades que chamam a url `http://localhost:3000/api/inserir`

```
const energy = require('../service')
const energia = server => {
    server.get('api/inserir', async (req, res, next)=>{
            const {
                     f1_tensao, f1_corrente , f1_potencia_ativa, medidor
                  } = req.params
            const obj = {
                    f1_tensao, f1_corrente , f1_potencia_ativa, medidor
            }
           const inserir = await energy.energy().insert2( obj )
            try {
                res.send( inserir );
            } catch (error) {
                res.send( error )
            }
            next()
        })

    server.get( 'api/medidor/:ip', async (req, res, next) =>{
            const { ip } = req.params
            try {
                res.send( await energy.energy().valores( ip ) )
            } catch (error) {
                res.send( error )
            }
            next()
        })
}

module.exports = energia
```

Quando tento consultar dados chamando minha url: `localhost:3000/api/medidor/1`, os mesmos demoram muito a serem retornados

Será que é devido aos muitos inserts que são feitos quase que ao mesmo tempo?

Porque eu já tentei consumir a api para fazer a consulta sem os inserts e os dados retornam quase que na hora.

Como posso resolver sem precisar criar outra api so para realizar consultas?

Esta é minha configuração npm:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "pm2": "^3.3.1",
    "restify": "^8.0.0",
    "restify-cors-middleware": "^1.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: Caro, já tentou aplicar algum tipo de filtro, por exemplo, range de datas para ver se a consulta melhora? não acredito que seja necessário criar outra api, por serem muitos dados talvez algum processo esteja atrasando a resposta. O que acontece dentro do service?

Comment: Na service está subdivido com as funções , updates, inserts, selects, o filtro já está aplicado, porque eu busco pelo parâmetro enviado.. Creio que terei que usar microserviços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é feita a conexão com o banco de dados?

Se por acaso for aberta a cada vez que o comando é executado ai está uma grande perca de desempenho, caso seja isso procura mais sobre pools de conexões que irá reduzir drasticamente o tempo de execução de comandos no banco de dados.

Segue um link que explica melhor como funciona o pool de conexões:

> http://cangaceirojavascript.com.br/lidando-com-conexoes-banco-plataforma-node/